# How to add checkbox in column header infragistics 2008 vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Is there is any option to create checkbox column header of the ultragrid in infragistics 2008.

I have used this coding,but its not working in infragistics 2008

```
this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout. Bands[0].Columns["IsActive"].Header.CheckBoxVisibility = HeaderCheckBoxVisibility.WhenUsingCheckEditor;
```

[image]

Kindly give some solution for this.